# mqtt TimeoutError: (WinError 10060) but It works when i change the publisher pc and subcricer pc

Tags: python, connection, timeout, mqtt

```
while True:
    aft = datetime.datetime.now()
    mongoQry = {"time": aft.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3], "Housing Input BWD Sensor": "NULL",
        "Inverter Run": "NULL",
        "Pressure Sensor": "NULL", "NGQuantity": "NULL", "RedQuantity": "NULL",
        "SilverQuantity": "NULL",
        "Alarm-Insert Disassembly Down Sensor": "NULL", "Alarm-Insert Input Up Sensor": "NULL",
        "Alarm-Housing Input Forward Sensor": "NULL", "Alarm-Housing Input Backward Sensor": "NULL"}
    strmongoQry = json.dumps(mongoQry)


    # bimongoQry = dict_to_binary(mongoQry)
    publish.single("paho/test/single",strmongoQry , hostname="192.168.0.12")
    print("Mongo success")
    sleep(1)
```

This is my very simple code
but The pc(192.168.0.12) cannot receive that
and when i send MQTT massage using The pc(192.168.0.12) to The computer that was publisher before,
it works.

I also turned off the firewall at pc(192.168.0.12)

Who will let me know what's wrong ..

Comment: And you have a MQTT broker running on 192.168.0.12?

Comment: yes .. mosquitto program ran on both computers and the port 1883 opened